# Pre-serialisation message objects - implementation?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, inheritance, composition

I have a TCP client-server setup where I need to be able to pass messages of different formats at different times, using the same transmit/receive infrastructure.

Two different types of messages sent from client to server might be:

- `TIME_SYNC_REQUEST`: Requesting server's game time. Contains no information other than the message type.
- `UPDATE`: Describes all changes to game state that happened since the last update that was posted (if this is not the very first one after connecting), so that the server may  update its data model where it sees fit.

(The message type to be included in the header, and any data to be included in the body of the message.)

In dynamic languages, I'd create an `AbstractMessage` type, and derive two different message types from it, with `TimeSyncRequestMessage` accommodating no extra data members, and `UpdateMessage` containing all necessary members (player position etc.), and use reflection to see what I need to actually serialise for socket `send()`. Since the class name describes the type, I would not even need an additional member for that.

In C++: I do not wish to use `dynamic_cast` to mirror the approach described above, for performance reasons. Should I use a compositional approach, with dummy members filling in for any *possible* data, and a `char messageType`? I guess another possibility is to keep different message types in differently-typed lists. Is this the only choice? Otherwise, what else could I do to store the message info until it's time to serialise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can let the message class to do the serialization - Define a serialize interface, and each message implements this interface. So at the time you want to serialize and send, you call AbstractMessage::Serialize() to get the serialized data.

Comment: In dynamic languages, you use reflection to see what you need to actually serialize. In C++, you call the interface function, and you get the serialized data(the derived class should knows what data in it need to be serialized). What is the difference?

Comment: OK. Does the interface function return a `void(*)`? Since it's an interface function I guess it must.

Comment: Can be a vector<char>, or a struct{char*, length}. In the format "messageCategory(fixed length),messageID(fixed length),serialized data".

Comment: Sensible/straightforward -- Thanks. I feel like a fool for not seeing this. Polymorphism, where have you been all my life.

Comment: See my post for an example implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some very high performance characteristics, I would use a self describing message format. This typically use a common format (say key=value), but no specific structure, instead known attributes would describe the type of the message, and then any other attributes can be extracted from that message using logic specific to that message type.

I find this type of messaging retains better backward compatibility - so if you have new attributes you want to add, you can add away and older clients will simply not see them. Messaging that uses fixed structures tend to fare less well.

EDIT: More information on self describing message formats. Basically the idea here is that you define a dictionary of fields - this is the universe of fields that your generic message contains. Now a message be default must contain some mandatory fields, and then it's up to you what other fields are added to the message. The serialization/deserialization is pretty straightforward, you end up constructing a blob which has all the fields you want to add, and at the other end, you construct a container which has all the attributes (imagine a map). The mandatory fields can describe the type, for example you can have a field in your dictionary which is the message type, and this is set for all messages. You interrogate this field to determine how to handle this message. Once you are in the handling logic, you simply extract the other attributes the logic needs from the container (map) and process them.

This approach affords the best flexibility, allows you to do things like only transmit fields that have really changed. Now how you keep this state on either side is up to you - but given you have a one-to-one mapping between message and the handling logic - you need neither inheritance or composition. The smartness in this type of system stems from how you serialize the fields (and deserialize so that you know what attribute in the dictionary the field is). For an example of such a format look at the FIX protocol - now I wouldn't advocate this for gaming, but the idea should demonstrate what a self describing message is.

EDIT2: I cannot provide a full implementation, but here is a sketch.

Firstly let me define a value type - this is the typical type of values which can exist for a field:

```
typedef boost::variant<int32, int64, double, std::string> value_type;
```

Now I describe a field

```
struct field
{
  int field_key;
  value_type field_value;    
};
```

Now here is my message container

```
struct Message
{
  field type;
  field size;

  container<field> fields; // I use a generic "container", you can use whatever you want (map/vector etc. depending on how you want to handle repeating fields etc.)
};
```

Now let's say that I want to construct a message which is the `TIME_SYNC` update, use a factory to generate me an appropriate skeleton

```
boost::unique_ptr<Message> getTimeSyncMessage()
{
  boost::unique_ptr<Message> msg(new Message);
  msg->type = { dict::field_type, TIME_SYNC }; // set the type

  // set other default attributes for this message type

  return msg;
}
```

Now, I want to set more attributes, and this is where I need a dictionary of supported fields for example...

```
namespace dict
{
  static const int field_type = 1; // message type field id

  // fields that you want
  static const int field_time = 2;
  :
}
```

So now I can say,

```
boost::unique_ptr<Message> msg = getTimeSyncMessage();

msg->setField(field_time, some_value);
msg->setField(field_other, some_other_value);
: // etc.
```

Now the serialization of this message when you are ready to send is simply stepping through the container and adding to the blob. You can use ASCII encoding or binary encoding (I would start with former first and then move to latter - depending on requirements). So an ASCII encoded version of the above could be something like:

```
1=1|2=10:00:00.000|3=foo
```

Here for arguments sake, I use a `|` to separate the fields, you can use something else that you can guarantee doesn't occur in your values. With a binary format - this is not relevant, the size of each field can be embedded in the data.

The deserialization would step through the blob, extract each field appropriately (so by seperating by `|` for example), use the factory methods to generate a skeleton (once you've got the type - field `1`), then fill in all the attributes in the container. Later when you want to get a specific attribute - you can do something like:

```
msg->getField(field_time); // this will return the variant - and you can use boost::get for the specific type.
```

I know this is only a sketch, but hopefully it conveys the idea behind a self describing format. Once you've got the basic idea, there are lots of optimizations that can be done - but that's a whole another thing...

Comment: So more of a compositional approach? If so, dummy members would be a necessity here, then, even if they were just pointers. I guess I can live with this; I tend to favour composition over inheritance 9 out of 10 times. No other solutions you can see? It really comes down to language basics.

Comment: @NickWiggill, no you don't need any "dummy members", the point is the message is self describing, it only includes the fields that you want to update - this also is suitable if you want to have a format based purely on deltas (i.e. only update the attributes that need updating)

Comment: How about a code example? The reason I'm asking questions is because the answer is not clear in terms of implementation.

Comment: @NickWiggill, something like that, C++ doesn't have a base class for everything, hence the reliance on the variadic type for the actual values (you can also use `boost::any`, but I prefer `boost::variant` - simply because to serialize you can use a visitor which will do it nicely.)

Comment: Of course. This is just like using an instance of class `Object` in C#, Java or ActionScript. Only boost::variant allows the elements to vary in type? Essentially you're using a dictionary/hash as an object you can dynamically add members to, and remove members from (if you want the latter). Of course even at O(1), there is a performance cost. But the simplicity is good.

Comment: @NickWiggill, It's trying to achieve a balance between a message format that is based on fixed structures with fixed members, and a message format where the attributes are dynamic. Both have advantages and you need to decide for yourself - which fits your requirements best.

Comment: It's a good answer and I've definitely learnt something (`variant`), would +3 you if I could. I'll need to think about it some more before I assign a winner though... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to simply have a header on all of your messages. for example, you might have a header structure that looks like this:

```
struct header
{
  int msgid;
  int len;
};
```

Then the stream would contain both the header and the message data. You could use the information in the header to read the correct amount of data from the stream and to determine which type it is.

How the rest of the data is encoded, and how the class structure is setup, greatly depends on your architecture. If you are using a private network where each host is the same and runs identical code, you can use a binary dump of a structure. Otherwise, the more likely case, you'll have a variable length data structure for each type, serialized perhaps using Google Protobuf, or Boost serialization.

In pseudo-code, the receiving end of a message looks like:

```
  read_header( header );
  switch( header.msgid )
  {
     case TIME_SYNC:
       read_time_sync( ts );
       process_time_sync( ts );
       break;

     case UPDATE:
       read_update( up );
       process_update( up );
       break;

     default:
       emit error
       skip header.len;
       break;
  }
```

What the "read" functions look like depends on your serialization. Google protobuf is pretty decent if you have basic data structures and need to work in a variety of languages. Boost serialization is good if you use only C++ and all code can share the same data structure headers.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out; maybe I was unclear in my question, which is essentially, "Given that I need an intermediate data structure until the time comes around to serialise and send, what is the most efficient way to store it in the interrim?" You're referring to what happens on the receiving end, and it is a great explanation, just not the answer to my current question.

Comment: I understand. Boost serialization would mean you don't need an intermediate, you just create "serialize" methods on your native types. If you really have temporaries protobuf can also work for that (I've used it like that) -- no need to create an in-between structure between your native data and serialized protobuf form.

Answer (score 0):

A normal approach is to send the message type and then send the serialized data.
On the receiving side, you receive the message type and based on that type, you instantiate the class via a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) (using a map or a switch-case), and then let the object deserialize the data.

Comment: I'm asking about how best to store my data until the time comes to serialise it, since I need a single object representing a single message that is first constructed, then a few milliseconds later, serialised and sent. "How best" refers primarily to ease of access, and secondarily to space efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Your performance requirements are strong enough to rule out dynamic_cast? I do not see how testing a field on a general structure can possibly be faster than that, so that leaves only the different lists for different messages: you have to know by some other means the type of your object on every case. But then you can have pointers to an abstract class and do a static cast over those pointers.

I recommend that you re-assess the usage of dynamic_cast, I do not think that it be deadly slow for network applications.

Comment: Here is [an example](http://www.nerdblog.com/2006/12/how-slow-is-dynamiccast.html) of dynamic_cast performance. This is a fairly well accepted fact of life in C++. I'm sorry, but two orders of magnitude speed reduction on certain high-frequency ops is more than I'm willing to accept.

Comment: @NickWiggill Thanks for your pointer. Is this for the same compiler and architecture that you are planning to use? Furthermore, are you sure that you wouldn't incur similar costs by taking a work-around? How much the particular use of a dynamic_cast would weight against the rest of your code and the network latency?

Comment: Multi-platform (Win, Deb Linux, MacOS) under gcc. I am very certain that I wouldn't incur similar costs. The simplest workaround is to use a message object with as many different members as are required to accommodate all different types of messages, which will cost a bit of space but not much else. I'll be sending out packets at about 20hz. And there is an immense amount of processing to go in between: a hi-def software raycaster, and all the unit AI and general game logic, and IO to stream in world chunks. Really, I just wanted to know from folks here if there were any more elegant ways.

Answer (score 0):

On the sending end of the connection, in order to construct our message, we keep the message ID and header separate from the message data:

- `Message` is a type that holds only the `messageCategory` and `messageID`.
- Each such `Message` is pushed onto a unified `messageQueue`.
- Seperate hashes are kept for data pertaining to each of the `messageCategory`s. In these, there is a record of data for each message of that type, keyed by `messageID`. The value type depends on the message category, so for a `TIME_SYNC` message we'd have a `struct TimeSyncMessageData`, for instance.

Serialisation:

- Pop the message from the `messageQueue`, reference the appropriate hash for that message type, by `messageID`, to retrieve the data we want to serialise & send.
- Serialise & send the data.

Advantages:

- No potentially unused data members in a single, generic `Message` object.
- An intuitive setup for data retrieval when the time comes for serialisation.